# How to decode a NCR to unicode character in C++

Tags: c++, unicode, decoding, ncr

I want to decode a NCR value something like &# 35686; to its equivalent chinese character. Example:test direct(&# 35686;&# 23519;) should be converted to test direct(警察) . I have tried the below algorithm similar to java

1. find the decimal value that is between &# and ; --ie. 35686
2. Convert to int
3. get the equivalent char by using char(35686) which will give the unicode char

In java , it produces expected output but in C++ it produces the string as test direct( fß) instead of chinese. 
Please help me  out of this.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to [so]! Please share a [MCVE]!

Comment: If you "convert" an integer to a `char` in C++, you get what you ask for: it truncates the value to the bottom 8 bits. Probably unlike Java: in C++, a `char` cannot hold a *textual* character but only a *value* - and then only 8 bits of it. Without seeing your code, I think you simply don't need to 'convert' to `char`.

Comment: How we can decode the NCR to its equivalent chinese character in C++